# Powershell Import-Module: prefix imported variables

Tags: powershell

Consider sample powershell module `sample.psm1` which exports single variable as follows:

```
$ROOT = "C:\root"
Export-ModuleMember -Variable ROOT
```

This can be imported specifying a prefix:

```
Import-Module .\sample.psm1 -Prefix "Sample::" -Force
```

Even though prefix works fine for referencing module functions (e.g. you can now do `Sample::SomeFunction`) it does not seem to work for variables, i.e.

`$Sample::ROOT` does **not** work, neither does

- `Sample::ROOT`,
- `$(Sample::ROOT)`,
- `Sample::$ROOT`,

they are imported and available through global names only (`$ROOT` in this case)

What are possible options for forcing a prefix on imported variables? What is a general best practice for dealing with imported variables?

manually prefixing module variables in module declarations could do, but it's kind of ugly approach to namespacing

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that generally you wouldn't want to export variables from a module, but instead provide getter/setter functions, for the same reasons that .NET classes don't usually use fields, but properties instead.

If you execute `Import-Module` with `-Verbose` on your module you'll see that functions are prefixed and variables aren't. I take that as a strong indication that prefixes on variables aren't supported.

However, you can use this code to access variables and functions in *myModule*:

```
$myMod = get-module myModule
& $myMod {$root}
```

This gives access to variables & functions in modules ahead of like named variables & functions outside of the module. (If you use that code to access a variable not in a module, but in an outer scope, you'll get the variable in the outer scope, because modules have access to variables in outer scopes.) By not exporting a module variable the only way to access it from outside the module  is by qualifying it with `$myMod`.

So not quite a namespace but close.